# Rename SharePoint list or group with spmeta2

Tags: sharepoint

How do i rename group or list with **[spmeta2](https://github.com/SubPointSolutions/spmeta2)**? 
Is this even possible?
I have tried looking for a solution here at [spmeta2 scenarios page](http://docs.subpointsolutions.com/spmeta2/scenarios/) - no luck.

I could not add spmeta2 tag, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

These are two questions.

List renaming can be done with ListDefinition and setting up correct Title of the list. Group renaming is not supported.

In general, SPMeta2 supports a limited amount of artifact to be "renamed". Lists and fields are fine, but some of the artifacts use the "Name" as a primary key so that SPMeta2 uses it to understand if artifact exists or not.

Should you have more questions fell free to reach out Yammer support network:
https://www.yammer.com/spmeta2feedback

Cheers!